# How to store centralized state for each FlatList item?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-context

My app has a calendar component that displays content for each day as you swipe horizontally (similar to the iOS Calendar app). I implemented this with a `FlatList` which renders a `DayContent` component for each day.

Each `DayContent` component has its own local state populated on render by reading from the database for the specified date. For simplicities sake, let's say each `DayContent` component displays a counter and a button that takes you to a new screen `EditCount` to edit the counter (this needs to be a separate screen since in my application the edit is more complicated than increment/decrement).

**Here is the problem:**

I first thought about implementing this `EditCount` screen by passing `count` and `setCount` in the router params. However, I noticed that React Navigation passes router params as copies and not by reference, so when I call `setCount` in the `EditCount` screen, the `count` is not updated in the `EditCount` screen although it is updated back in the `DayContent` component.

I then considered storing the `count` and `setCount` variables in my central state management system (Context API). However, I am unsure how this would work since each day in the calendar needs its own `count` and `setCount`.

Ideally, I don't want to update the database in `EditCount`, so if there are any other methods I would appreciate them.

I have been struggling with this seemingly straightforward problem for a few days now, please let me know if you have any ideas.

**EDIT**

The `data` I pass to my `FlatList` is an Array of length 7. The way I have it set up is that if I swipe to the edges of the array, (ie first, second, or second last, last index in the array) I recreate the array centred around the current day to create the illusion of an infinite list.

So every time I recreate this array of length 7, I assume it re-renders all the days and makes an API call to each one (ie 7 times on each re-render). Not sure if this is the most efficient method.

I am using Firebase Firestore to make my database requests, I haven't looked too deeply into how the caching mechanism works, haven't done any explicit caching though.

```
const DayContent = ({ dateStr }) => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    const dbContent = getContentFromDate(dateStr);
    setCount(dbContent);
  }, []);

  const handleEdit = () => {
    navigation.navigate("EditCount", { count, setCount });
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleEdit}>
        <Text>Edit</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {count}
    </View>
  );
};

const EditCount = () => {
  const { count, setCount } = useRoute().params;

  return (
    <View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={navigation.goBack}>
        <Text>Go back</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>=
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={setCount((prev) => prev + 1)}>
        <Text>Increment</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={setCount((prev) => prev - 1)}>
        <Text>Decrement</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      {count} /////// Does not update
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Could you share more infos for me to understand? (1) I assume that if there is 30 days in your `FlatList`, will you call your `API` 30 times on mount? (2) In your `DayContent` component, `handleEdit` function should bring us to `"EditCount"` rather than `"EditContent"`? (3) In `EditCount`, should we remove the `handleEdit` function? If not, are we supposed to change `content` with `count` and `setContent` with `setCount`? (4) Are you using a caching library like `react-query` for fetching your `API`?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I added an edit above the code block to answer some of your questions. (1) Updated above, (2) yeah that's a typo, (3) sorry that shouldn't be there either, I updated the code accordingly, (4) answered above ^

Comment: Thank you for your edit, it will definitely help us understand the context. Could you add a minimal reproduction of the `FlatList` component as well?

Comment: [Here](https://snack.expo.dev/@kojon74/smart-waffles) is a minimal reproduction of the `Flatlist`, it's a bit complicated since it also relies on navigation as well. Let me know if this makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can update the `EditCount` screen's `count` params value separately too, by running

```
navigation.setParams({
  count: count + 1,
});
```

in addition to the original state update.

But I think this is not the best approach because you will have 2 separate states, one in `EditCount` and another one in the `DayContent`.

For a better solution I think you could use a global state management library (I have used Valtio for similar cases, but any other will work also) or context.

The general logic would be like this:

- set up the store, and save the day data into the store when you receive it from API, day data should object / array with some kind of ID for each day, you could use the date as the ID
- create a mutation which will have 2 arguments: day ID and count, this mutation has to find the correct day from the store and then update the days count value
- whenever some component changes the day's the count, call out this mutation function with the day ID and new count value

For doing this with Valtio, the code would look something like this

Set up the store:

```
import { proxy } from 'valtio'

export const store = proxy({
    days: [],
})
```

Save the data to the store

```
const setInitialDayCount = useCallback(() => {
    // from API
    const day = { dateStr: '2023-03-15', count: 0 }
    store.days.push(day)
}, [])
```

Update the day data when it is changed

```
const updateDay = useCallback((dateStr: string, count: number) => {
    const day = store.days.find((day) => day.dateStr === dateStr)
    if (day) {
        day.count = count
    }
}, [])
```

Use the day's count from global state

```
const { days } = useSnapshot(store)

const day = days.find((day) => day.dateStr === dateStr)
const count = day?.count
```

Comment: This is great! I did consider using global state management but I was wondering if this would be the best solution considering the `days` state could get very large especially if I need to store data for every day. Wouldn't it be a problem if `days` is too big?

Comment: I think it won't be an issue. I'm working with global stores (vuex) where the store size could be multiple MBs.

Also you can use the global store only for the day you are editing and keep everything else local.

There are also some methods to optimize the data structure, you can use [normalized data](https://redux.js.org/usage/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape) for quicker data access.

In general the global state management libraries are built with perfromace in mind.

Comment: That makes sense, I have one final question before accepting, how do I prevent every single component in the `FlatList` from re-rendering every time I make a single update to the `days` state? Ideally, I want to only re-render the component that corresponds to the day that has been changed.

Comment: You could use `React.memo` around the component you have in `renderItem`. Another option would be to use an array of IDs as the `data` in `FlatList`, and then retrieve and edit the normalized day data from the store by using the ID. Note that the array of IDs should change only when you retrieve the data or add some new days. To sum everything up, there are many ways to do it, which one to select depends on how complex is the data and how do you want to structure your state.

Answer (score 1):

For **readability**, **performance** and **scalability**, consider using `setParams` if it meets your needs.

```js
const EditCountScreen = () => {
  const { setParams, goBack } = useNavigation();
  const { count, setCount } = useRoute().params;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.editCount}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
          setCount((prev) => prev + 1);
          setParams({ count: count + 1 });
        }}>
          <Text style={styles.h1}>+</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.h1}>{count}</Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
          setCount((prev) => prev - 1);
          setParams({ count: count - 1 });
        }}>
          <Text style={styles.h1}>-</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={goBack}>
        <Text style={styles.h1}>Back</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```